# I'm having trouble with this

Tags: python

```
def get_age():
    age = int(input())
    if age < 18 or age > 75:
        raise ValueError('Invalid age.')
    return age


def fat_burning_heart_rate(age):

    heart_rate = (220 * 0.70) - age
    return heart_rate

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        heart_rate = fat_burning_heart_rate(age)
        age = get_age()
        print('Fat burning heart rate for a', age, 'year-old:', 
               heart_rate, 'bpm')

    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        print('Could not calculate heart rate info.')
```

The primary issue that I have so far is when I go run this code it generates a name error saying that 'age' is not defined. This occurs when I try to assign heart_rate = fat_burning_heart_rate(age). I suspect that it has something to do with the way that I pass the function parameter. But what can I do to fix it?

Comment: You are setting the value of age after trying to use it, either set it before or pass the function itself. `heart_rate = fat_burning_heart_rate(get_age)`

Comment: You have your function calls in the wrong order. You need to use `age = get_age()` first, then `heart_rate = fat_burning_heart_rate(age)`. The way it is now, `age` isn't even defined before you use it.

Comment: It got rid of the primary problem, But now it has been replaced with this issue: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'function' is there something wrong with my equation?

Comment: Okay I'm getting output now thanks to your second statement. Now all I need is the correct equation. This is what It wants: Write a program that calculates an adult's fat-burning heart rate, which is 70% of 220 minus the person's age. If you look at the equation for heart rate that is what I have. However when I go to run the program the bpm reads 119.0 as opposed to 129.5

Comment: Use heart_rate = 0.7*(220-age) instead. A slight english misinterpretation.

Answer (score 0):

```
def fat_burning_heart_rate(age):

heart_rate = (220 * 0.70) - age
if age < 18 or age > 75:
    raise ValueError('Invalid age.')
return heart_rate, age

if __name__ == "__main__":
  try:
    age = int(input("Input age: "))
    heart_rate, age = fat_burning_heart_rate(age)
    print('Fat burning heart rate for a', age, 'year-old:',
          heart_rate, 'bpm')

except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
    print('Could not calculate heart rate info.')
```

You don't need get_age(). You can add that code to fat_burning_heart_rate().

Answer (score 0):

age = get_age() seemed to be in the wrong position within the code, also I believe you misinterpreted the expression for heart rate. This code will allow for both definitions and will properly flag any errors.

```
def get_age():
    age = int(input())
    if age < 18 or age > 75:
        raise ValueError('Invalid age.')
    return age

def fat_burning_heart_rate(age):
    heart_rate = (220 - age) * .7
    return heart_rate


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        age = get_age()
        heart_rate = fat_burning_heart_rate(age)
        print('Fat burning heart rate for a', age, 'year-old:', 
heart_rate, 'bpm')

    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
        print('Could not calculate heart rate info.')
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this code.

```
def get_age():          #gets user input and checks to see if valid age range
    age = int(input())
    if age < 18 or age > 75:
        raise ValueError('Invalid age.')
    return age


def fat_burning_heart_rate(age):   #calc heart rate with given user input(age)
    heart_rate = (220 - age) * .70
    return heart_rate

if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        age = get_age()         #calls def get_age and fat_burning_heart_rate
        bpm = fat_burning_heart_rate(age)
        print('Fat burning heart rate for a', age, 'year-old:', bpm, 'bpm')
    except ValueError as excpt:
        print(excpt)
        print('Could not calculate heart rate info.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue was that you had:

```
try:
        heart_rate = fat_burning_heart_rate(age)
        age = get_age()
        print('Fat burning heart rate for a', age, 'year-old:', 
               heart_rate, 'bpm')
```

When you should've had:

```
try:
        
        age = get_age() # Age first prior to calling fat_burning_heart_rate
        heart_rate = fat_burning_heart_rate(age)
        print('Fat burning heart rate for a', age, 'year-old:', 
               heart_rate, 'bpm')
```